# What is AWS load balancing? Should I create multiple ec2 instance with same files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, autoscaling

I am new to AWS. I would like to activate load balancing. I need to know that should I create multipl ec2 instance with the same files? Or only one instance is enough?. What will happen while heavy traffic?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/

Comment: @GauravLad   Thanks . Can you tell me something on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Elastic Load balancer (ELB) is for distributing traffic across multiple EC2 instances. You will be registering the instances with the ELB. Even when instances fail and new instances are added to ELB, the traffic is evenly distributed among the remaining active registered instances. Please see the documentation: 
 [AWS Elastic Load Balancing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elastic-load-balancing.html)

If you have only one instance, ELB will send traffic only to that. But, what is the use of ELB then? It serves no purpose to have only 1.

If you need to scale out as the traffic increases, you need to use AWS Auto Scaling : 
 [AWS Auto Scaling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/WhatIsAutoScaling.html)

Comment: Thank you. So to use ELB I should create multiple instances with same files and add it under one ELB. SO it will distribute traffic across number of instance I have created right?

Comment: usually that is the use case. i.e., you run the same app on multiple instances and the requests are balanced across those apps running on those multiple instances. But the instances need not be identical copies.

Comment: oophs.. need not to be identical copies? I am running web application, in this case All the instance should be identical copies right?

Comment: you need to run web application on all the instances. But each instance can be of different hardware configs. Each one can also run other apps not related to the web apps. Some may not run those different apps. That is what I meant when I said not identical. Your question was like all should be same and no difference. There is no such rule.

Comment: Yeah Got it... Thanks

Comment: If your question is answered, you can accept the answer :)